# C pass array by value vs pass array by reference

Tags: c, arrays, pass-by-reference, implicit-conversion, function-declaration

Hello everyone so I have been learning C and I came across this example and I don't really find the logic behind. this is not a technical question regarding code I was looking more for an explanation. 
this is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void set_array(int array[4]);
void set_int(int x);

int main(void)
{
    int a = 10;
    int b[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
    set_int(a);
    set_array(b);
    printf("%d %d\n", a, b[0]);
}

void set_array(int array[4])
{
    array[0] = 22;
}

void  set_int(int x)
{
    x = 22;
}
```

the output is `10 22`

basically my question is why does the 22 that is passed from the set_array function rewrites the 0 on the b array and actually prints but the 22 that is passed from the set_int function doesn't get passed nor printed.

Thank you all!

Comment: There is no "pass by reference" in C - `void set_array(int array[4])` is actually `void set_array(int* array)`

Comment: `array` decays to a pointer in `set_array`. And `[]` is effectively a pointer dereference. So to make `set_int` equivalent to `set_array` it is more like: `void set_int(int *x) { *x = 22; }`

Comment: *Everything* in C is pass-by-value. The only difference is what form that value takes. For arrays, their expressive value is a pointer to first-element.

Comment: @kaylum so basically it will only overwrite the value if a point it to an array such as in the set_array function right?

Comment: You did not accept one of the two answer solving your problem, why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C passing by reference means passing an object indirectly through a pointer to it. If you will pass an object directly to a function then the function will deal with a copy of the value of the object.

Compare two function calls in this demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f( int x )
{
    x = 10;
}

void g( int *x )
{
    *x = 10;
}


int main(void) 
{
    int x = 0;

    printf( "Before call f: x = %d\n", x );

    f( x );

    printf( "After  call f: x = %d\n", x );

    putchar( '\n' );

    printf( "Before call g: x = %d\n", x );

    g( &x );

    printf( "After  call g: x = %d\n", x );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Before call f: x = 0
After  call f: x = 0

Before call g: x = 0
After  call g: x = 10
```

That is we passed to the function `f` the object `x` directly. So the function deals with a copy of the object `x`. Changing the copy does not influence on the original object `x` declared in main.

As for the function `g` then it got an access to the object `x` indirectly through a pointer to it. So changing the pointed object we changed the object `x` declared in main.

As for arrays then when an array is passed to a function it is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element. So the function in fact gets elements of the array by reference through this pointer. Using the pointer and the pointer arithmetic we can change any element of the array.

This function declaration

```
void set_array(int array[4]);
```

is equivalent to the following declaration

```
void set_array(int array[]);
```

and the both declarations are adjusted by the compiler to the declaration

```
void set_array(int *array);
```

So the function deals with a pointer - the pointer to the first element of the array used as an argument of the function call.

The call of the function set_array in your program

```
set_array(b);
```

is equivalent to the following call

```
set_array( &b[0] );
```

because arrays used in expressions as for example as a function argument expression are implicitly converted to pointers to their first elements.

Comment: so in a resumen that worked because the new value that i assigned was directed into a pointer which in this case was the array, is that right?

Comment: @diego The array was converted to pointer to its first element and using this pointer in the function you have the direct access to elements of the array for example by applying the subscript operator array[i] where i is some index .

Answer (score -3):

C functions, when receiving parameters **other than** arrays and pointers (arryays are actually translated to pointers) don't update the source value because they created a **copy** of the value passed by the parameter.

Should your function be:

```
void  set_int(int *x)
{
    x = 22;
}
```

Then you're working with the source variable. But since you didn't declare a pointer, but a variable, you'd have to call it like this:

```
set_int(&a);
```

To ensure you're passing a's memory reference, rather than it's content.

Comment: You need to derference `x`: `*x = 22`

Comment: "other than arrays and pointers". Whilst I understand what you are trying to say, that statement is not technically correct. In C, everything is pass by value - even pointers and arrays. It means that arrays and pointers also cannot be changed inside a function. Only the memory referenced by the pointer/array can be changed and not the pointer/array itself. This is indeed often confusing for new C coders but it is a very important distiction to make.

Comment: @kaylum: Arrays are not passed by value.